# Minecraft Bukkit coding Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Here is the full code for it:

```
public void trackAll() {
    int north = count(Direction.North) * 25;
    int east = count(Direction.East) * 25;
    int south = count(Direction.South) * 25;
    int west = count(Direction.West) * 25;

    if ((north == 0) && (east == 0) && (south == 0) && (west == 0)) {
        this.player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Not a valid tracking compass.");
        return;
    }

    for (Direction direction : Direction.values()) {
        int length = count(direction) * 25;
        if (length != 0) {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Set players = new TreeSet();
            for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                if (this.player.canSee(player)) if ((on(player, direction) & !player.equals(this.player))) {
                    players.add(player.getDisplayName());

                }
            }
            FancyMessage message = new FancyMessage(direction + " (" + length + "): ").color(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA);
            int i = 0;
            for (String str : players) {
                if (i == players.size() - 1)
                    message.then(str).color(ChatColor.GRAY).tooltip(ChatColor.GREEN + "Click here to track " + ChatColor.RESET + str + ChatColor.GREEN + ".").command("/track " + ChatColor.stripColor(str));
                else {
                    message.then(str).color(ChatColor.GRAY).tooltip(ChatColor.GREEN + "Click here to track " + ChatColor.RESET + str + ChatColor.GREEN + ".").command("/track " + ChatColor.stripColor(str)).then(", ");
                }
                i++;
            }

            message.send(this.player);
        }
    }
}
```

And I also have another issue "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Block"

```
public int count(Direction direction, boolean b) {
     int length = 0;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Set toDelete = new HashSet();

     for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
       Block next = this.middle.getRelative(BlockFace.valueOf(direction.toString().toUpperCase()), i);

       if (next.getType() == Material.COBBLESTONE) {
         length++;
         toDelete.add(next); } else {
         if (next.getType() == Material.STONE) {
           length++;
           toDelete.add(next);
           toDelete.add(this.middle);
           break;
         }
         length = 0;
         toDelete.clear();
         break;
       }
     }

     if (b) {
       for (Block block : toDelete) {
         block.getWorld().playEffect(block.getLocation(), Effect.STEP_SOUND, block.getTypeId());
         block.setType(Material.AIR);
       }
     }

     return length;
   }
```

I currently don't have someone that can look over the code I personally do not see the issue but I've been working on it for hours so yeah ;/ Thanks. This code is to do with a Minecraft plugin it's tracking a players location and sending the information to the player that executed the command.

Comment: Which line give that error?

Comment: In the first code text the following line gave the error "for (String str : players) {" the error is on "players" 

and the second code text the following line gave the error "for (Block block : toDelete) {" the error is on "toDelete"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use

```
Set<String> players = new TreeSet<>();
```

and

```
Set<Block> toDelete = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: I think an explanation as to why this needs to be done should also be added. As it stands, the OP probably has no idea why this works any better than before. Maybe explain why `Set` will be `Set<Object>` or such?

Comment: @Frontear Agree. Maybe you add you own answer and I will remove my. I'm not very good at explaining.

Comment: Just explain to the player that a Type must be defined inside of the <T>, otherwise it sets to default, and the return types of what he tried to iterate mismatched the Type they were trying to iterate by.

Comment: @Frontear but I don't want to do it. Also this is perfect opportunity to earn a badge for deleting accepted answer.

Comment: Apparently you can't delete accepted answer.